# ArangoSearch support for multiple fields search

Tags: full-text-search, arangodb

Does ArangoSearch support search on multiple/all fields of a collection. I want to be able to search a text on all fields of a given collection. Does ArangoSearch support such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can let a View index all fields (attributes) of your documents very easily:

```
{
  "links": {
    "yourCollection": {
      "includeAllFields": true
    }
  },
  …
}
```

In queries you need to be explicit about which fields to search in however:

```
FOR doc IN yourView
  SEARCH doc.field1 == "foo" OR doc.field2 == "foo" OR doc.nested.field == "foo"
  RETURN doc
```

It is not possible (yet) to express this using a wildcard, like `SEARCH doc.* == "foo"`. Possible workarounds are to maintain a separate attribute which combines the content of all the individual fields you want to search in (but you need to make sure that it stays in sync with the source attributes), or to use a query builder of sorts to generate a disjunction like above.