# ArangoSearch across all fields

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to setup ArangoSearch:

1. I have a collections (in fact many collections, but currently testing with one)
2. I've created a view with `"includeAllFields": true,`
3. I am able to search like this `search ANALYZER(doc.field == "string", "text_en")`

The issue is that I need to search across all (indexed) fields. I have quite a lot of different (unknown amount) fields and it will be difficult to specify all of them using OR logic.

I saw similar question ([ArangoSearch support for multiple fields search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772552/arangosearch-support-for-multiple-fields-search)) created few years ago and it was impossible at that time.

Is it still impossible to search across all indexed fields ? Is there any other workaround except combining all fields into one and using that for search.

Answer (score 0):

If dynamic AQL generation is kind of hard, maybe you can try concat the fields:

```
FOR doc IN myCollection
    LET combined = CONCAT(doc.title, " ", doc.description, " ", doc.author ....)
    FILTER ANALYZER(CONTAINS(combined, "search term"), "text_en")
    RETURN doc
```

If you have a lot of fields you can try an external tools like elasticsearch.